# Load Model in HMVC

Tags: codeigniter, hmvc

I am trying to load a model within the same module from a controller.

```
$this->load->model('pendingAccountModel');
```

but the model could not be loaded.

the module dir is accounts.
the model file path is: app/modules/accounts/models/pendingAccountModel.php
the model decleration is:

```
class PendingAccountModel extends Model {  
  function __construct(){  
    parent::__construct();  
  }  
}
```

this is the controller who loads the model:

```
class PendingAccount extends MX_Controller {

  function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
  }

  function register($data_arr)
  {
    $this->load->model('pendingAccountModel');
  }

}
```

CI 1.72 with latest hmvc
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

had a quick read through the HMVC docs ~

`$this->load->model('pendingAccountModel');`

the docs suggest that you should include the module name in the include path

so try (perhaps) `$this->load->model('accounts/pendingAccountModel');`

also note your "PendingAccount" controller needs to be in:

`app/modules/accounts/controllers/PendingAccount.php`